# How to search content on the Lifehacker site?

Tags: search, lifehacker

I found out back in '06 there was a Firefox plugin that did it. But it's not out there in the add-ons area anymore.

Comment: This is probably the worst example of a tech centric site disabling essential technology.  It's almost as bad as schools being the only tech-free zone that students are supposed to be learning in.

Answer (score 17):

You could always cheat with Google:

[site:lifehacker.com windows](http://www.google.ca/#hl=en&q=site%3Alifehacker.com+windows)

Comment: @Moab any public site :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a firefox add-on called [search this site](https://addons.mozilla.org/af/firefox/addon/92023/)

I don't know if it's any good cause I never used it. I'm using a [similar extension on chrome](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ampaaokifoiijaegiboaoncicpekfbdo) thought and it works flawlessly.

And you can always use google site feature just like John T suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about locating the search box on their site - it's usually at the top right of the screen (sometimes gets covered).  If you are asking about searching on a search engine like Google, then yes, there is a way to restrict to specific sites - look under something like Advanced search options and there should be a place to put a site to restrict searches to.  For Google it would be "what_you_are_searching_for site:sitetosearch" so "Batman site:lifehacker"

Comment: I've attempted to find a search box on the homepage in 3 different browsers and it just ain't there. There's a "Share" box. But that's for adding content, not searching.

Answer (score 1):

They [removed the search feature recently](http://lifehacker.com/5714674/how-to-search-lifehackercom-using-google) because of [security issues](http://lifehacker.com/5712785/):

> Due to the recent security issues, certain features of the site have been disabled. Among them? Search. But let's be honest: search didn't really work that well anyway. Here's a better way to search for your favorite posts.

Their recommended workarounds are to either use the Google `site:` operator, or to add lifehacker to Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Wow. If that's the case, then they really need new programmers. Or they just need to educate the ones they have. Search is nearly as essential for a site like theirs as the content itself. Yeesh!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome or Opera, it is easy to [build a custom (Lifehacker) search provider](http://mvark.blogspot.com/2010/10/adding-new-search-provider-easiest-with.html) for those browsers so that you don't even have to use the **site:** operator every time you want to search something on Lifehacker.